# How to block server.js in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

Problem statement

I have server.js in which I have a config file

My server.js

1. Some imports
2. require config.js -> api call to get config /promise call
3. Server start using value in config
4. Before I get config, server tries to start and crash as config is empty.

How do I block process to go beyond config.js step

Comment: please provide a minimal code sample so we can better understand what the underlying problem is :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot start your server until the promise is fulfilled so that you actually have a non-empty config.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand completely your situation. But, if you want to start your server after the request you can use the `then` or `async / await` to do that. Considere this simple snippet:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const getConfig = require('./config');

const expressConfigs = (app, config) => {
  app.get('/', (req, res) =>  {
    res.send('Hello World!');
  });

  app.listen(config.port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${config.port}!`);
  });
};

(async () => {
  const config = await getConfig();
  expressConfigs(app, config);
})();
```

OBS: config soube export one Promise, you could use node-fetch for that.